# Masking out one texture on top of another with precision detailing

Tags: texturing, materials, masking

In my model, you will notice a silver paint that is applied to the surface of the black material. I'm looking to layer the silver material on top of the black material and then perfectly mask out the silver material in order to get those silver graphics and rune symbols using nodes. I got confused by some of the tutorials I was watching, sadly. In my file you'll notice the silver is covering the entire model and i've used a mix shader on it and the black material (i'm assuming my nodes are set up poorly, but I'll let you be the judge). I've attached my blender model and screenshots of both the 2D design and current WIP of the model. Thanks for your time!

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sR6V44sb4HPcL7RrCI7K7kba5W1oH4yI)

[image: Piece I am modeling]

[image: Ideal finished look]

[image: Black Material]

[image: Silver paint I want to mask out on top of black material]